# Writing the UML for a java program

Tags: java, uml

my first question;

I am new to Java, been playing around with object orientation for a few months. I want to write a UML class diagram however I am trying to research it for the past 4-5 hours. Every time I find information it opens up another can of words and quite simply, I haven't got the experience to understand the terms that it uses.

My program is constructed as follows:

```
class 1 (newMote) - creates a new instance of the object
class 2 (calibrator) - sets up all the gui for the system and registers components for events
Class 3 (Responder) - this is where the work happens, all my logic is in here and my actionevents
```

the following classes are for the api that I am using (sourced elsewhere)

```
class 4 (WiiUseAPI) - the api
class 5 (WiiUseAPIManager) - the manager for the api
class 6 (wiiMote) - lists all the methods from the wiiuseJ library
```

If I could get some instruction on where to look to better understand what I am doing that explains all details in real laymens terms or some instruction of how these classes would be constructed I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: This link is very helpful for starting out on UML class diagrams: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/umlClassDiagrams.pdf

Answer (score 2):

For your code auto generate UML u can use [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/) an Eclipse plugin.